# Selecting non-matching fields in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables as follows:
Contact, Custom_Field, Custom_Field_Value.

Each contact can have one Custom_Field_Value record for each Custom_Field.  So there is a 1:many relationship between Contact and Custom_Field_Value but it isn't quite that simple.

Everything works fine - except for one edge case where I need to select Contacts that have a particular Custom_Field not set (i.e. no corresponding Custom_Field_Value record exists linking to the Contact and the Custom_Field).  This is surprisingly difficult.  I can't just use the normal "left join and look for NULL" approach because they may have a different custom field - but not the one I am looking for.  I need to say "Where Custom_Field_ID=10" but I can't because the thing I'm looking for does not exist.

My line of thinking was heading in this direction, but I'm just tying myself in knots now:

```
Select ID, First_Name, Last_Name, CF_ID  From 

(

(Select Contact.ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Custom_Field_Value.ID as CFV_ID, Custom_Field_Value.CustomFieldID as CF_ID, TextValue 
From Contact Inner Join Custom_Field_Value on Contact.ID = Custom_Field_Value.ContactID 
Where Custom_Field_Value.CustomFieldID=23 Order By Contact.ID)

UNION

(Select Contact.ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Custom_Field_Value.ID as CFV_ID, Custom_Field_Value.CustomFieldID as CF_ID, TextValue 
From Contact LEFT Join Custom_Field_Value on Contact.ID = Custom_Field_Value.ContactID 
Order by Contact.ID)

) as A


Group BY `ID`, CF_ID ASC
```

I don't want to create blank records for every possibility because there could be millions of records and every time someone adds a custom field, the database would have to insert millions of corresponding blank records.

It would be really great if we could do this:

```
Select ID From thingy 
EXCLUDE
Select * From thingy Where x = true
```

This is a nasty one, but I know there'll be someone out there who will love it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the crazy SQL I ended up with - created dynamically by users.  Just publishing it in case its any use to anyone. (Any tips on optimisation are very welcome!):

The problem is that not only do I have to select missing dynamic records, I also have to join together Left Join queries into one result.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM Contact 
        WHERE (...some dynamic stuff...) 
    ) 
    UNION All 
   (SELECT Contact.* FROM Contact Inner Join Contact_Campaign_Link ON Contact.ID=Contact_Campaign_Link.Contact_ID 
       WHERE ((Campaign_ID=31))
   ) 
UNION All 
    (SELECT * FROM Contact 
        WHERE (CustomerID=3) 
        AND (NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM Custom_Field_Value cfv2 
                WHERE (cfv2.ContactID = Contact.ID) 
                AND (cfv2.CustomFieldID =27) )) ORDER BY Contact.ID)
            ) As tbl 

GROUP BY tbl.ID HAVING COUNT(*)=3 Order by ID
```

Comment: In `SELECT DISTINCT Contact.* FROM Contact LEFT JOIN Custom_Field_Value`, you probably don't even need the `LEFT JOIN`. And then you won't need the `DISTINCT` anymore.

Comment: TheVedge - thanks, you're completely right.  I've updated the final result: it's almost starting to look simple.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I have a better understanding now. I was trying to pull it off without a subquery, but I'm not sure if I can.

Can you try

```
Select Contact.ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Custom_Field_Value.ID as CFV_ID, Custom_Field_Value.CustomFieldID as CF_ID, TextValue 
From Contact LEFT Join Custom_Field_Value on Contact.ID = Custom_Field_Value.ContactID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Custom_Field_Value cfv2 WHERE cfv2.ContactID = Contact.ID AND cfv2.CustomFieldID=23)
Order by Contact.ID
```

The NOT EXISTS subquery should only return rows where the contact has no value for that field.

Comment: I can't because there could be a record there:)  There could be 2 Custom_Field records and a Contact could have one but not the other one that I need to know is missing.  So I would get the other record.  The only other way I can think is that I loop though all the other custom fields and go "And (CustomFieldID <> 1) and (CustomFieldID <> 2)... omitting the one I need"

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully it will help

Comment: Brilliant - one last thing was required.  Select DISTINCT on the main query.